# JQuery/Javascript functions with dynamics id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in this situation, where I have a div and a button:

```html
<div style="display:none" class="partita" onkeypress="editPartita(e,???????)" >
...
</div>
<button id="plusPartite"></button>
```

Onclick of this button there is another function:

```js
function ShowNewPartite(i) { 
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("partita");
    a[0].style.display = 'unset';
    var newI = parseInt(i) + 1;
    var newId = "partita" + newI ;
    a[0].setAttribute("id", newId);
}
```

that assign an dinamic id on div and I want that if the user keypress on the div "partita",there is another function that is:

```js
editPartita(e,id){
if(e.which == 13){
}
...
}
```

that save on DB the elements.
How I call back the id that is created in a ShowNewPartite(i) for a new div "partita",in the function editPartita(e,??)  ?
Thankyou

Comment: Don't dynamically change an `id`. You can use data-attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes instead. Don't ever mess with an element's `id` once you set it and don't ever have two elements that share an id in the same scope of an application.

Comment: If you create snippets, make sure it makes sense to run them.

Comment: Setup the `onkeypress` handler from JavaScript using `Element.prototype.addEventListener`